# how do I find the generator matrix of binary cyclic codes with given number of column but not rows?

Tags: polynomials, coding-theory

I am supposed to find the generator matrix of a polynomial generator $g(x)=1+x+x^3+x^4\cdots$ with given $(n,k)$, $n=7$ but $k$ is not specified...

how many shifts should I go to get a systematic form?

Comment: The codewords are the coefficient of polynomials of $<7$ which are divisible by $g(x)$. So, from this, you see specifying $n$, $g(x)$ gives you $k$.

Comment: So how do I go on to find the generator matrix?

Comment: Found the answer if someone is interested.